# Looping SQL INSERT inserts into multiple rows

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to make a loop that inserts the values i want into a MySQL database, this loop inserts the right values, but on different rows.

```
if($qa != "Sallader"){
                $query = "ALTER TABLE bestallningar2 ADD ".$qa."1 int, ADD ".$qa."2 int, ADD ".$qa."3 int, ADD ".$qa."4 int, ADD ".$qa."5 int;";
                $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
                $x1 = $_SESSION["".$qa."1"];
                $x2 = $_SESSION["".$qa."2"];
                $x3 = $_SESSION["".$qa."3"];
                $x4 = $_SESSION["".$qa."4"];
                $x5 = $_SESSION["".$qa."5"];
                $query2 = "INSERT INTO bestallningar2 (".$qa."1, ".$qa."2, ".$qa."3, ".$qa."4, ".$qa."5) VALUES('$x1', '$x2', '$x3', '$x4', '$x5');";
                $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query2);
```

As said i want it to insert all the values into the same row, which it does not. Really have no clue what to do, thanks in advance!

Comment: `values ('x'),('y'),('z')` how you insert multiple values

Comment: Can you include some example data and how it's currently working v's how you intend it to work.

Answer (score 0):

[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2IDIh.png)

As you can see on the image the values are on different rows, 5 by 5, i want all 15 to be on the same row. I supose it's becuase in the code I esentially maake 3 different querys but I don't know how to work around it.

Answer (score 0):

Your insert statement is only inserting 5 fields.  Create $x1-$x15 and then insert all 15 using 1 insert statement.